# How can I test this method call with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Code to be tested:

```php
// Add the activation provider argument to the factory definition
$factoryDefinition = $container->getDefinition('gremo_subscription_factory');
$factoryDefinition->addArgument(new Reference($providerId));
```

Test method should check the `addArgument` method, including `$providerId` argument. I'm just learining PHPUnit and right now I'm only able to call `$this->anything()`:

```php
$container->expects($this->at(3))
    ->method('getDefinition')
    ->with('gremo_subscription_factory')
    ->will($this->returnValue($factory));

$factory->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addArgument')
    ->with($this->anything());

$this->pass->process($container);
```

How can I check that argument type is `Reference` class, and (in turn) its argument is exactly the string `$providerId`?

Comment: those semicolons on new lines are pretty bad looking

Comment: @llnk agree... any help about the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty complicated, especially since the `Reference` class is not dependency injected and method call doesn't return anything. However, I think you can get around it using [argument constraints](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertThat.tables.constraints). Here's how I would do that second clause:

```
$factory->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addArgument')
    ->with($this->logicalAnd(
        $this->isInstanceOf('Reference'),
        $this->attributeEqualTo('attribute', $providerId)
    ));
```

The second item in the `logicalAnd()` is basically just checking the `Reference` object that is created to see if `$providerId` gets assigned correctly (I'm not sure what happens to `$providerId` in the `Reference` constructor, but I'm assuming it gets saved to an instance variable or something).

This sort of thing, however, is moving into the territory of testing implementation details of the `Reference` class, so tests like this are not great for maintaining SRP. All of this would be better solved by refactoring your code. Generally speaking, if it's hard to test, it is probably not the test suite's fault. If you are able to, consider changing things on that end first, rather than writing overly-clever tests.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the piece of code is something common in Symfony 2 and there is no way to avoid the new `Reference` call. Don't know what its constructor will do with my value, and as you said it doesn't matter, as I have to test MY code. I'll try and report back...

Comment: It doesn't matter what the constructor does, as you should mock the entire thing.  $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
                     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                     ->getMock();

Comment: @rockstarz: That doesn't help. In this case, it's impossible to mock the Reference object, since it isn't dependency injected.

Comment: And actually, I think there is a way to avoid hardcoding the Reference object...pass it into your `process()` method as a second parameter. That will make this whole thing really easy to test.

Comment: @theunraveler I don't call process() directly, it's the framework. Plus can't use attributeEqualTo, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Reference.php

Comment: Ok works, even if I can't understand how logical and works. How attributeEqualTo('id', $providerId) is related to the addArgument paramenter?

Comment: That depends on the `Response` class. It's safe to assume, therefore, that the `Response` class assigns that variable in its constructor to a property called `id`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this test is extremely brittle, and will break if you subclass `Response` and do anything other than assigning that parameter in the constructor to a property called `id`. FWIW.